# How to use css property linear-gradient to gradually change color from red to yellow to green?

Tags: html, css, colormap

I want to create a legend using html, css which contains change of color gradient from green to yellow to red. I have tried using linear gradient property of css. However, what I got so far is given below:

```css
#color_range {
  height: 280px;
  width: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #DAECB8 0%, #E33127 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="color_range"></div>
```

[My code for color gradient](https://jsfiddle.net/avijit1258/aqped4g1/)

I need a figure like this:

[image: jet color map from green to yellow to red]

How can I make a legend like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change: `background: linear-gradient(to top, #DAECB8 0%, #E33127 100%);`

To: `background: linear-gradient(red,yellow,green);`

You can also change it to: `linear-gradient(to top, green,yellow,red);` but I don't think that `to top` is necessary

```css
#color_range {
  height: 280px;
  width: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(red,yellow,green);
}
```

```html
<div id="color_range"></div>
```

To understand how linear-gradient works in CSS please read: [CSS Gradients](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

Also take a look at this page that can be helpful when using CSS gradients: https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
#color_range{
  height:280px;
  width:40px
  background:linear-gradient(red,yellow,green);
}
```

You can also use the color codes for these colors .